# WPF ComboBox to ObservableCollection binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, observablecollection

I know there is a few topics on this problem but haven't find any solutions to this problem I have..

I have a ViewModel with an observable collection and I want to bind this collection to a combo box. However, there is no selected item, no index, just the collection itself.

in the XAML I have

ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding OSCollection}" **DisplayMemberPath="OSCollection.Name"**

I believe the trouble lies with the bold above, I want to get a property from the collection called name, but like I say - no item will be selected before the bind.

I could use a foreach or something to extract the properties from the collection but I don't think this is the MVVM and WPF way.

Any help would be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DisplayMemberPath specifies the path to the display  property.So it should be **Name** not **OSCollection.Name**

```
  ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding OSCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
```

Comment: Thanks, simple in the end!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sajeetharans comment:
When binding to a List of Type `T`, `DisplayMemberPath` will always refer to the Name of a `Property` of `T`. In your case it is only "Name"